# OptionMenu not working after items are updated

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror, optionmenu

I have two option menus and the contents of one is updated by selecting a value from the other. Whilst this is a fairly common situation I still can't seem to make it work. I now have it so that the options update but upon selecting an item from the second, updated box it throws the following error:

```
self.SelectFrame['menu'].add_command(label=frame, command=lambda v = self.varFrame, l=frame:v.set(1))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'`
```

The code for the declaration of the optionmenu in question is below:

```
    self.varFrame = Tk.StringVar()
    self.Frames = ["",""]
    self.SelectFrame = Tk.OptionMenu(botLeftFrame, self.varFrame, *self.Frames)
    self.varFrame.set("None selected")
    self.SelectFrame.pack(side="left", padx = 5, pady = 10)
```

In another method in the same class is this code:

```
def runSelectionChanged(self,*args):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Public\dbsDetectorBookingSystem.accdb')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT RunFilePath, RunID FROM tblRuns")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        if row.RunFilePath == self.varRun.get():
            chosenRunID = row.RunID

    sqlString = "SELECT LocalFilePath, RunID FROM tblFrames WHERE RunID=?"
    cursor.execute(sqlString, str(chosenRunID)) 
    self.userFrames = cursor.fetchall()
    self.Frames = ["",""]
    for frame in self.userFrames:
        self.Frames.append(frame.LocalFilePath)


    newFrames = self.Frames
    self.varFrame = ""
    self.SelectFrame['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    for frame in newFrames:
        self.SelectFrame['menu'].add_command(label=frame, command=lambda v = self.varFrame, l=frame:v.set(1))
```

The error is thrown when you select an item from the menu after it has been updated, I do not understand why as I am sure that the lambda command gives it the ability to be set. I have tried various other ways if phrasing this command without lambda but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.varFrame` is not normal `string` but `StringVar` and you can't set value by

```
 self.varFrame = ""
```

This way you replaced `StringVar` by normal `string` and now you can't use `self.varFrame.set()` (in you error it is `v.set()`)

You have to always use `set()`

```
 self.varFrame.set("")
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that